# Problema con arrays en visual studio (problemas del programa)

Tags: c++, array

Cuando quiero poner el límite de mi vector con una variable, el programa no me deja. Esto no me sucedía con code blocks.

El código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int save,num,c=0,digito,mayor=0;
    cout << "ingrese un numero:";
    cin>>num;
    save=num;
    while (num>0){
        num/=10;
        c++;
    }
    cout<<"tu numero tiene: "<<c<<" digito"<<endl;
    int vect [c*2];
    for(int i=0;i<(c*2);i+=2){
    vect[i]=0;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<(c*2);i+=2){
        digito=save%10;
        vect[i]=digito;
        save/=10;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<c*2;i++){
        cout<<vect[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
       for(int i=0;i<c*2;i++){
        if(vect[c]>mayor){
            mayor=vect[i];
        }
    }
    cout<<"el mayor es "<<mayor<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: saludos te recomiendo no poner imágenes que aparte son difíciles de leer, si colocar el código e indicar cual es el comportamiento esperado es decir lo que intentas obtener

Comment: Muestra el codigo como texto.

Comment: ok ya comente es abajo

Comment: hazlo en la propia pregunta, no como si fuera respuesta

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Los arrays en C++ deben tener un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación. Como tal, el compilador de VS sigue el estándar.

Comment: Donde está el array o el vector?

Answer (score 1):

```
int vect [c*2];
```

Aquí estás intentando crear un array de tamaño fijo usando una variable... algo que se conoce con las siglas VLA (Variable Length Array) y que no está soportado por el estándar... luego es posible que te funcione con algunos compiladores pero no es la forma de resolver el problema.

Tu quieres darle al vector un tamaño en tiempo de ejecución y para eso has de recurrir a la memoria dinámica:

```
int* vec = new int[c*2];
```

Por supuesto, todo `new` ha de tener su correspondiente `delete` para que el programa no tenga fugas de memoria:

```
int main()
{
  // ...

  delete[] vec;
  return 0;
}
```

Aunque claro, siendo estrictos, el problema se puede resolver tranquilamente sin usar ni un solo vector:

- Calcular el número de dígitos de un número entero positivo es tan sencillo como calcular su log10 y sumarle 1:

  ```
  log10(1)   = 0
  log10(10)  = 1
  log10(100) = 2
  // ...
  ```
- Para calcular el dígito más alto solo necesitas iterar sobre sus dígitos y quedarte con el más alto... pero sin vectores

Es decir:

```
int num;
std::cout << "ingrese un numero:";
std::cin>>num;

int numDigitos = static_cast<int>(std::log10(num))+1;
std::cout << "Tu numero tiene: " << numDigitos << " digito(s)\n";

int mayor = 0;
while( num != 0 )
{
  int digito = num % 10;
  num /= 10;

  if( digito > mayor )
    mayor = digito;
}

std::cout << "El mayor es " << mayor << '\n';
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias la verdad es que entendi todo y ahora solo queda manos a la obra